# Regex to find every second new line (match only new line characters)

Tags: regex

Regex to find every second new line  (match only new line characters)

Input:

```
LINE1
LINE2
LINE3
LINE4
LINE5
LINE6
```

Output:

```
LINE1LINE2
LINE3LINE4
LINE5LINE6
```

I have tried `\n[^\n]*\n` but it matches text as well for replacement and does not give desired output.

I am having issues in matching every second new line character only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your objective is to produce your "output" from your "input" I suggest you focus on that as your question and not try to force a particular approach to achieve that result.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and review. The reason I need to restrict it in a certain way because the solution that I need cannot have matched string as replacment inputs. this is the reason I am finiding it difficult to match new line characters only. Apologies for not being clear earlier

Comment: If the lines are an even number: `\n(?=(?:.+\n.+\n)*.+$)` https://regex101.com/r/8WfdLP/1

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regular expression

```
^(.*)\n(.*\n)
```

and replace each match with `$1+$2`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDvBLj/3/)

Alternatively, you could simply match each pair of lines and remove the first newline character. That requires a bit of code, of course. As you have not indicated which language you are using I will illustrate that with some Ruby code, which readers should find easy to translate to any high-level language. Suppose `str` is a variable holding your multi-line string. Then:

```
r = /^(?:.*\n){2}/
s = str.gsub(r) { |s| s.sub(/\n/, '') }
puts s
LINE1LINE2
LINE3LINE4
LINE5LINE6
```

Comment: What I have generates your desired result. Is that not sufficient, considering that your result can be obtained by keeping everything in each pair of lines except the first newline or converting the first newline of each pair of strings to an empty string?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and review. The reason I need to restrict it in a certain way because the solution that I need cannot have matched string as replacment inputs. this is the reason I am finiding it difficult to match new line characters only. Apologies for not being clear earlier

Answer (score 2):

For an even number of lines, you could make use of a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right side is 0 or more times repetition of 2 lines that end with a newline, followed by matching the last line and the end of the string.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
\n(?=(?:.+\n.+\n)*.+$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\n` Match a newline
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:.+\n.+\n)*` Match 0+ times 2 lines followed by a newline
  - `.+$` Match any char except a newline 1+ times and assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8WfdLP/1)

Output

```
LINE1LINE2
LINE3LINE4
LINE5LINE6
```